# Magento2 Payment methods render list missing on custom Checkout module

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I'm modifying all Magento 2 to accept login with mobile phone instead of email. Register, login, account info, backend, login at checkout, everything is going well.

But when I use my own `checkout_index_index.xml` instead of the core one, the object which stores the list of renders of each payment method (`rendererList`) is not filled in.

In the moment of the checkout, using the original `checkout_index_index.xml` I got this when I debug `list.js`:

```
rendered list in the beginning >> 
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] list.js:30
```

Using my `checkout_index_index.xml`:

```
rendered list in the beginning >> 
[] list.js:30
```

The object with the payment methods in both situations:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
method: "paypal_express"
title: "PayPal Express Checkout"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
method: "purchaseorder"
title: "Purchase Order"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
method: "checkmo"
title: "Check / Money order"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
method: "free"
title: "No Payment Information Required"
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

So, the `rendererList` used in list.js to render each payment method for my custom module is empty. I spend a whole day trying to find where does this object is filled in without success.

I must say I'm editing `checkout_index_index.xml` to use my own js files on checkout steps like this:

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Tmo_Checkout/js/view/shipping</item>
     <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
     <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Tmo_Checkout/js/view/form/element/username</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">customer-email</item>
                <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">We'll send your order confirmation here.</item>
                </item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="before-login-form" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                      <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-login-form</item>
                      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <!-- before login form fields -->
                      </item>
               </item>
               <item name="additional-login-form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                   <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-login-form-fields</item>
                   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                      <!-- additional login form fields -->
               </item>
          </item>
     </item>
</item>
```

Finally, the questions are: how do I fill that `rendererList`?? or where Magento does it?? or how can I specify custom js files for checkout without touching `checkout_index_index.xml`?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, instead of intercept the layout creation to rewrite the section where I wanted use my JS files instead of the core original ones, I delete that code and replace it with a require-js file, like this:

Path: `MyCompany/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

Content:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/customer-email-validator':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/model/customer-email-validator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/email-validator':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/view/payment/email-validator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/view/form/element/username',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/view/shipping',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/view/authentication',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default':'MyCompany_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
    }
}
};
```

It was so much simpler than my first answer and works exactly the same but with less effort :)

Answer (score 6):

The `rendererList` is [observable JavaScript array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) provided by the `Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list` component.

In order to use `rendererList` in custom payment module the following should be done:

1. Create in your module `view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file and declare new payment renderer component (adding as an image to give an idea):

[image]

2. Create the `Custom_Payment/js/view/payment/custom_payment.js` component
   and add `rendererList` component as a dependency. It will allow you to add custom payment renderer into `rendererList` array:

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'custom_payment',
                component: 'Custom_Payment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custom-payment-renderer'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

3. Create `Custom_Payment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custom-payment-renderer` component and assign template to render custom payment:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/iframe',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-information'
    ],
    function ($, Component, setPaymentInformationAction) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Custom_Payment/payment/custom-payment'
            },
            ...
        });
    }
);
```

4. Finally, create `Custom_Payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/custom-payment.html` template to have custom payment form.

All Core Payment modules modifies `rendererList` in the way described above.

I hope answer gives you an idea how `rendererList` is filled with payment methods.

It is recommended to add custom js files via `checkout_index_index.xml`. This has to be done very carefully, respecting nested levels of `jsLayout` component.

Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I'm not adding a new custom payment method, what I need is to add my custom JS files to the `checkout_index_index.xml` thats the only thing I need. But when I copy that file to my module folder in order to edit it, then what I get is a completely empty `rendererList`. 
I saw before those JS files filling in the rendererList... But, do I need to have a copy of all of them in my folders to fill in that list of renders??

Comment: @hiperboreo would you mind to show your version of checkout_index_index.xml file to understand the issue?

Comment: I edited my question, I added a piece of `checkout_index_index.xml` where I'm using custom JS files instead of core JS files.
Right now I'm thinking in intercept the layout creation on class LayoutProcessor, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already found how to solve my problem, it's interesting, I explain it:

1.- I already had a custom Checkout module, I created the next preference on my `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"
           type="Tmo\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPreference" />
```

That class receives the content of `checkout_index_index.xml` as an array, so we can access it in the same way.

2.- I modified the content of `process` function, adding the following:

```
if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
         ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']
         ['children']['customer-email']['component']))
{
  $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
           ['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']
           ['customer-email']['component'] = 'Tmo_Checkout/js/view/form/element/username';
}

if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['authentication']['component']))
{
      $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['authentication']['component'] = 'Tmo_Checkout/js/view/authentication';
}
```

And so on... What I'm doing is following the nested structure of `checkout_index_index.xml` until I reach the tag I need to change. To know this structure I printed the entire `$jsLayout` to the debug log and looked for my tag.

I have 5 blocks like these, each one checks if the content exists on that specific part of the array and then replace the original string, which is a JS path/filename, with a string containing my custom JS path/filename.

The above code is working as expected :)

This class also adds, or more specifically 'merge', into that layout more stuff like the address fields, shipment methods, renders for payment methods, etc...

I choose to use a preference instead of a plugin because I'm also using protected attributes on other part of this function.

Comment: Hello.... I need to use also my own LayoutProcessor instead of Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor but my own is not being called. What else did you do?

Comment: It works if you create a preference for that Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Debug entry point is `\Magento\Vault\Plugin\PaymentVaultConfigurationProcess::beforeProcess`.

You can check if your method is in the active list and why it is deactivated.